# Drupal : Nodes not getting created for uploaded images. Gives "user warning: Duplicate entry" error

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am getting the following error when I am uploading some images in my Drupal CMS tool

```
Access denied

user warning: Duplicate entry '434062-434065' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO node (nid, vid, title, type, uid, status, created, changed, comment, promote, sticky) VALUES (434062, 434065, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'image', 167, 1, 1404885608, 1404885608, 2, 0, 0) in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
user warning: Duplicate entry '434065' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO node_revisions (nid, vid, title, body, teaser, timestamp, uid, format, log) VALUES (434062, 434065, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '', '', 1404885608, 167, 1, '') in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
user warning: Duplicate entry '198423' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO files (fid, nid, filename, filepath, filemime, filesize) VALUES (198423, 434062, '_original', 'images/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg', 'image/jpeg', '95858') in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
user warning: Duplicate entry '198424' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO files (fid, nid, filename, filepath, filemime, filesize) VALUES (198424, 434062, 'thumbnail', 'images/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg', 'image/jpeg', '2824') in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
user warning: Duplicate entry '198425' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO files (fid, nid, filename, filepath, filemime, filesize) VALUES (198425, 434062, '70x70', 'images/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg', 'image/jpeg', '1908') in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
user warning: Duplicate entry '198426' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO files (fid, nid, filename, filepath, filemime, filesize) VALUES (198426, 434062, '50x50', 'images/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg', 'image/jpeg', '1419') in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
user warning: Duplicate entry '198427' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO files (fid, nid, filename, filepath, filemime, filesize) VALUES (198427, 434062, '90x90', 'images/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg', 'image/jpeg', '2486') in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
user warning: Duplicate entry '434062' for key 1 query: INSERT INTO node_comment_statistics (nid, last_comment_timestamp, last_comment_name, last_comment_uid, comment_count) VALUES (434062, 1404885608, NULL, 167, 0) in /var/www/html/cms/includes/database.mysql.inc on line 172.
```

On digging deeper I found that the nid/vid/fid values which is used above by drupal to save the content in db are already existing, So I guessed it must be a problem of auto_increment values being wrongly set in these tables. But when I checked the AUTO_INCREMENT in the correspnding tables, only `node` table had AUTO_INCREMENT on nid and that too was already set to 434510. Other tables don't have an auto_increment on primary key.

I want to know from where is drupal picking this nid / vid / fid values. It is in some config file/code or from somewhere within the db. I tried updating the cache_content table but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by setting the correct values in `sequences` table in the drupal DB.
Aparently Drupal doesn't rely on the Auto Increment value of fields in the respective tables, it goes looking for the next id in the `sequences` table.

Updated values of node_nid, node_revisions_vid & files_fid to the corresponding "max + 1" valuee in nodes, node_revisions and files tables.